# Debian Linux cron stubbornly refuses to run at right time

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I have a Debian Linux server, recent install.  It has this cron job:

```
7 1 * * *       /do/something/important.sh
```

As I read that, it should run at 1:07am.  Instead, it runs at 5:07pm.

So, wrong timezone, right?  No...I'm in US/Pacific and:

```
# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Mar  5 20:29 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific
# date
Fri Mar  9 16:54:52 PST 2012
```

That is the right time as I post this.

Now, cron did run for a couple days with the wrong timezone (default was MST).  I fixed that by changing /etc/localtime.  I also restarted cron (/etc/init.d/cron restart).  I've local-gen'd, too.

That job is running at 17:07 Pacific time consistently...something else I missed?

Comment: Tough one. Tried reinstating the crontab, yet? i.e. add another cronjob to force it to reload the crontab.

Comment: Added a date piped to a tempfile to run at 6pm...checked back and it hadn't fired.

Comment: Would've been to simple...
Does the user maybe still have a different local timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer is:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This is a debian-specific thing. I’m not sure of the fine details of what it does, but it fixed the problem.

This command was formerly `tzconfig`.

Answer (score -1):

Just restart cron, it will use your local timezone setting. It worked for me.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Comment: Based on the question age and the other answer's suggestion of installing a timezone fix do you know when the timezone fix was added to Debian?